# Median in ordinal data

Tags: ordinal-data, median, likert

I'm really having trouble with this one even though it's probably really easy for the professionals. I can't figure out the median... I'm getting 3 but not sure if that's right at all. Can someone help me?

1. Not at all likely = 4
2. Not likely = 59
3. Rather likely = 652
4. Very likely = 488

---

Sorry, supposed to be

4.Very likely =488

3.Rather likely = 652

2.Not very likely = 59

1.Not at all likely = 4

Comment: Yes. The median is 3, as you suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Quick answer:** There are 1203 observations, of which 601.5 is half. So if the observations are sorted from smallest to largest the`1`s ns `2`s do not account
for nearly half of the observations and the middle observation (median) is among the `3`s.

```
(4+59+652+488)/2
[1] 601.5
```

**More complete:** In R, you can put all 1203 observations into a vector `x` as follows:

```
x = rep(1:4, times=c(4, 59, 652. 488)
```

Then we can get various numerical and graphical descriptions of the data
using various procedures in R, as follows:

```
table(x)
x
  1   2   3   4 
  4  59 652 488 

summary(x);  length(x);  sd(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   1.00    3.00    3.00    3.35    4.00    4.00 
[1] 1203         #  sample size
[1] 0.5880589    #  sample standard deviation

hist(x, br=.5:4.5, col="skyblue2", ylim=c(0,700), label=T)
```

[image]